# Do you need to use different materials for a battery busbar?

Tags: batteries, busbar

I'm interested in building custom Lithium Ion battery packs out of reclaimed 18650 cells. I've seen several videos of people doing this and some of them use copper for the positive busbar and brass for the negative busbar.

Is there a particular reason for this?

EDIT: To be more clear, I'm talking about wiring up multiple 18650's together in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Packs are even made with only nickel strips. They must have chosen to use that so that the positive and negative are differently colored.